# Is Parse Server platform Live Query good for private Chat?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

As you know, the Parse platform Live query can be used for sending live data. Parse Server handles the database of data with MongoDB in its back-end. For live queries of Parse, we have to define the table that we want to live query from in the Parse server's configurations.

So for Private messaging, we cannot make a table that has live query feature for each user, we have to define one table that saves all chat data and fetch each user's chat data from one table. My question is, can MongoDB handle for example fetching data from thousands or millions of rows from one table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, the format of your question isn't quite what we answer on SO. If you could share some code or show us some attempts you made, we'd be happy to help. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a table but that doesn't mean all object will be public if you add ACL's. If the ACL matches the currentUser only those rows will be returned.

In the latest version you can pass a sessionToken to

`await query.subscribe(sessionToken)`

Comment: You are right, but i mean, for example we have a chat table with thousand of rows in it, fetching data from that table for specefic rows, is ok for mongo db? can mongo db handle this kinda thing good?

Comment: Sorry your question was confusing. Yes mongo / parse can handle the traffic if you scale properly. I don't see a reason to fetch an entire table in one query for Private Messaging. Look into skip/limit for paging.